# Update record in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Page1:

```
select * from category
```

After `fetch`data and display on particular on `td`.There is `Edit` button across every `td`.I need when I press `Edit` Button I get `cid` of particular record and want to go on other page where I have `update` query and want to update record with that `cid`.

I did with

```
javascript:window.location.href=update.php?h=<?php $fetch['cid'];?>`
```

some thing like that.But I want an alternative way to get `cid` from one page to another for update record, without Javascript.

```
<?php echo $result['cid'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['cname'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['descc'];?></td>
```

Page2:

```
$idd=$_REQUEST['h'];
mysql_query("update category set cname='".$cn."',descc='".$cd."' where cid='".$idd."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Your code is widely open to SQL injection attacks, please use mysqli or PEAR.

Comment: I think @sockfd means MySQLi or PDO, but yes, definitely -- you will get hacked.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but this is basic i need to improve my level how can i learn advance php ? any reference ?

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/, or directly related to this question http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: @MLeFevre Thanks another good link.

Comment: I use this [MeekroDB](http://www.meekro.com/) library. This library is quite easy to use and works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
if you don not want to use javascript then you need to use form and hidden input field for `cid` inside the form.

try like this:

```
  <td>
        <form action="update.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="echo $fetch['cid']">
            <input type="submit" name="cmd" value="Update">
        </form>
    </td>
```

this line:

```
javascript:window.location.href=update.php?h<?php $fetch['cid'];?>
```

should be:

```
javascript:window.location.href=update.php?h=<?php echo $fetch['cid'];?>
```

after that you can get like this:

```
$_REQUEST['h'];
```

params in the url passes like this:

```
url?param_name=param_value
```

you missed `=` in the url.

Comment: you mean `javascript:window.location.href=update.php?h=<?php echo $fetch['cid'];?>` - you forgot `echo`

Comment: Thanks for correction.Kindly tell me solution but with not javascript

Comment: @Falling Dusk: try my updated answer. let me know if you got it

Comment: In this case `cid` shown in url.Can we do this with any other secure way?

Comment: use form and set form method to post.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `MySQLi` (`mysql_*` is deprecated).

Try this, **Page 1**
*Query your database and show a table of result, with a button to edit the row.*

```
<?php

// Connect to your DB
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Query Your DB & Load Data
$categories = array();
$query = 'select * from category';
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $categories[] = $row;
    }
}

// Close DB connection
$mysqli->close();

// Now Display Your Form
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $category['cid'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $category['cname'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $category['descc'] ?></td>
        <td>
            <form action="update.php?cid=<?php echo $category['cid'] ?>">
                <input type="submit" name="cmd" value="Update">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

**Page 2** *When the `Edit` button is clicked, you will br brought to this page `update.php`. Then you can handle the update request like this ...*

```
<?php

// Connect to your DB
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Get the category id
$cid = isset($_GET['cid']) ? intval($_GET['cid']) : 0;

// Proceed if you got the category id
if ($cid)
{
    // Query db about this category id

    // Display Edit Form

    // Handle Edit Form Save
}

// Close DB connection
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your information, the official MySQLi tutorial:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

The PHP manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/